# Check that a value can only exist once in a column per another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean, constraints

We have a table like the one below:

```
=# CREATE TABLE items (item_id INT NOT NULL, revision VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, is_newest_rev BOOLEAN NOT NULL, UNIQUE (item_id,revision));

=# SELECT * FROM items;
 item_id | revision | is_newest_rev
---------+----------+---------------
     250 |       1A | f
     250 |       1B | t
     199 |       1F | t
      40 |       1A | f     <-note this, false
      40 |       1B | f     <-note this, false
      40 |       1C | t     <-note this, true
```

The above table is valid.

The following table is invalid:

```
=# SELECT * FROM items;
 item_id | revision | is_newest_rev
---------+----------+---------------
     250 |       1A | f
     250 |       1B | t
     199 |       1F | t
      40 |       1A | f     <-note this, false
      40 |       1B | f     <-note this, false
      40 |       1C | t     <-note this, true
      40 |       1D | t     <-ERROR! 40 | 1C is already marked as true!
```

I need to create a constraint to check an insert query before it is applied to the table; to check that there is only one instance of `t` per `item_id` and `revision`.

So, if I were to try to run `INSERT INTO items VALUES (40, '1D', 't');` it would fail because `40, 1C` is already marked as `t`. If all revisions of `40` were marked as `f`, THEN it would work. Hope this makes sense.

Sorry for bad worded title, I found it hard to name the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be adressed with a [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html).

Consider:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX items_custom 
    ON items (item_id, is_newest_rev)
    WHERE (is_newest_rev = 't');
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4aadbaf7ee7303d006e8f6a64da51787)**:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    item_id INT NOT NULL, 
    revision VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
    is_newest_rev BOOLEAN NOT NULL, 
    UNIQUE (item_id,revision)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX items_custom 
    ON items (item_id, is_newest_rev)
    WHERE (is_newest_rev = 't');

insert into items values(40, '1A', 't');
insert into items values(40, '1B', 'f');
insert into items values(40, '1C', 't');

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "items_custom"
DETAIL:  Key (item_id, is_newest_rev)=(40, t) already exists.
```

Comment: @leetbacon . . . This answers the original version of your question, which is very reasonably interpreted as "at most one true value per item".  I would suggest that you accept this answer (or another) and ask a *new* question about mandating exactly one such column.

Answer (score 1):

**Calculate (Don't Store) Application State**

Perhaps you shouldn't be storing application state inside the databases like that.  You calculate application state.

Consider using sequential data instead of trying to update state.

Consider that <strike>event</strike> *even* a revert is a new revision.

```
 item_id | revision 
---------+----------
     250 |       1
     250 |       2
     199 |       1
      40 |       1
      40 |       2
      40 |       3
```

Or, add timestamps for each revision, as below.

```
 item_id | revision | timestamp
---------+----------+-------------------------
     250 |       1  | 2019-10-16 07:22:00-05
```

Then, create table as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE items (item_id INT NOT NULL, revision INT NOT NULL, *...*, UNIQUE (item_id,revision));
```

Select using something like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY revision DESC LIMIT 1
```

The other option is to test for the state before and after inserts.

**Manually Testing Status**

You can specify that **item_id** and **revision** fields are **UNIQUE**, but that doesn't seem like what you want.  Seem that you want the **is_newest_rev** field duplicated for **true** values.

I believe you must write a **SELECT** statement, or a **COUNT** statement, and test the value of it before you perform your insert.  Probably want to do it afterwords too if multiple processes are accessing the database at the same time.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE item_id = 40 AND is_newest_rev = 't';
```

If the count is >= 1 then don't insert.  But, beyond that, I don't believe most SQL allows the type of entity constraints you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger as below

```
       Create trigger check before  Insert 
        On table for each row as
         If(Select count(*) from (Select 
           item_id,  
         count(distinct is_newest_rev)
         From table where 
        item_id=:new.item_id group by 
          item_id,
           having count(distinct 
            is_newest_rev)=2)>0
         Then
          //dont insert

        Else
          {Insert into......} 
        End if
        End
```

Comment: Am I to use `table` or `items` instead of table?

Comment: Items as your table name is items